# Motion tracking, scene doesn't line up with tracked data.

Tags: 3d-view, tracking

I fallowed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ysof3atAng) and watch some others. I used the video from the tutorial (the same one he used for motion tracking). I successfully imported the video, add the track points, and tracked them. When I set the orientation for the 3d scene it didn't really work. The camera was at a wrong angle the scene didn't really line up and the track points in the 3d scene weren't level like their supposed to be. The tracking points in the 3d scene did line up with the position of the original tracking point though.

Is there something I might be doing wrong missing a step or something?

Comment: Your question is too vague to know what you did wrong, please add more information. For help on motion tracking read the following links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42332/1853 **and** http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8934/some-data-failed-to-reconstruct-motion-tracking **and**http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful

Comment: also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/how-to-align-the-camera-in-a-solved-motion-tracked-scene/28888#28888

Comment: The other post helped as well as this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY I think my issuse might have had somthing to do with KeyframeA and KeyframeB.

Answer (score 0):

About the tracking points level ... maybe you have not set up the camera settings properly. Matching the cam settings (lens, sensor etc.) to the real camera, the footage was taken with, once did the thing for me - which you **always** have to do to get a proper result.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a low quality answer right now. This info would be better left as a comment. Please give more information so this post can be more beneficial: link to blender manual page, helpful posts about the topic elsewhere, clear guidelines on how to find correct settings, etc.

Comment: ok - will keep that in mind, thanks for the info