# Motion tracking camera angle strange

Tags: tracking

I made marks and solved the camera. In the constraints menu, I selected the camera solver and set floor. However, the camera angle is not harmony.

What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42329/599

Comment: Did you set X and Y axis on the orientation tab? Did you set origin, floor and wall for the scene? Additionally you can manually re-orient a scene. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/how-to-align-the-camera-in-a-solved-motion-tracked-scene/28888#28888 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/correct-tracked-camera-orientation/10708#10708