# How can I fix the orientation of the camera so it is above the grid?

Tags: camera, tracking

[image: Camera is below grid here like it was shot from a below angle but IRL it was shot from an above angle]

This is my first-time camera tracking in Blender and I have no idea how I would fix this, the tracking points are above the camera when they're meant to be below. Does this matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align the camera in a solved motion tracked scene?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/how-to-align-the-camera-in-a-solved-motion-tracked-scene) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/correct-tracked-camera-orientation/10708#10708